# A question of a propsition in Principles of Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

There is a propsition in the sec 2,chap 0 of this book：

```
    An analytic variety V is irreducible if and only if V* is connected.
```

Here $V^*$ denotes smooth points of V. However,a singular algebraic curve such as $y^2=x^3$ is irreducible as a curve of $ \mathbb{C^2}$ but singular at 0 so $V^*$ is not connected.It contradicts this propsition and I don't know what's wrong with me.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with you. :) $V^*$ is connected; don't be deceived by the standard picture, which only shows the _real_ part of the curve.

Comment: Oh,my god!I'm sorry for this silly question.Thank you very much.

Comment: Dear karlbmg, you're not the first person to mix up the real and complex pictures, and I'm sure you won't be the last.